# c# read string from txt continuously and save to program when starts to minimize response time

Tags: c#

I make a program in c# and i read from a txt file.
I use a thread to read automatically a lot of times from file, the same string (serial) and i use decryption code. I want to save this value somewhere in program when application starts and other classes read from there, to minimize response time because this app run in old computers.

Comment: Please provide the code you're working with.  It'd also be nice to get a copy of that text file if possible.

Comment: One solution: create your own class, and store the value to a field in a new object of that class. Then pass a reference to that object to every other object that you create that needs this information.

Comment: You can also check: https://csharpindepth.com/articles/singleton or https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/singleton-design-pattern/